# Protobuf 2.5.0 bug?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers

I've migrated from google protobuf v. 2.4.1 to v. 2.5.0 (no other change).

I had a perfectly working client-server [android<>gae dev server] communication using 2.4.1.
Now with 2.5.0 it is broken.

Without any modification to the .proto file, I've setup my client and server with the new 2.5.0 jar, and with the new protoc executable I've generated a new source file for client and server from the same proto file.

Now I get this error on the server when I'm trying to parse the message:

```
VerifyError: class ... overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
```

full stack:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.mta.pb.ACM$MyRequest overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
**at com.mta.server.p.AndroidServletP.doPost(AndroidServletP.java:91)** <- my code
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:57)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    ...etc
```

Things I've already tried:

1) Reading the changelog, I've tried to change the parse code from:

```
            request = MyRequest.parseFrom(requstBlob);
```

to

```
            request = MyRequest.PARSER.parseFrom(requstBlob);
```

(this is the same line 91 that you see in the stack trace).
It didn't change a thing. Same error.

2) I've tried to parse the message manually:
I printed out the base64 string coming to the server, converted it into binary

```
base64 -d in64 > out64.bin
```

than

```
protoc --decode=MyRequest my.proto < out64.bin > tmp.txt
```

And it parses it perfectly.
So the problem is only at the parsing part of the new protobuf.

3) I've tried taking ReqType out of MyRequest, no effect.

For reference: the relevant protobuf definition

```
/**
 * Master request object
 */
message MyRequest {
    optional RequestContext context = 1;
    optional MyReport myReport = 2;
    optional CategoryRequest catRequest = 3;
    optional GetMessage getMessage = 4;
    optional SearchRequest searchRequest = 5;
    enum ReqType {
        UNDEFINED = 1;
        REGISTER = 104;
        UPDATE = 123;
        GET_PAYLOAD = 100;
        SEARCH = 200;
        REPEAT_GCM = 623;
        REPEAT_PREPARE = 842;
    }
    optional ReqType reqType = 10;
    optional bool repeat = 11;
}
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: few hours of unfruitful research I've rolled back to 2.4.1 and it's working again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would guess you did not upgrade / recompile something. In protobuf 2.4.1 version in the jars.

in the **GeneratedMessage** class, **getUnknownFields** was a final method in 2.4.1 but in 2.5.0 it becomes:

```
  //@Override (Java 1.6 override semantics, but we must support 1.5)
  public UnknownFieldSet getUnknownFields() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
        "This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.");
  }
```

and is overridden in the generated class. You may need to recompile all your classes that use generated protocol buffer classes.

Given the messages

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.mta.pb.ACM$MyRequest overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
```

This tells you you are running code **generated** with Protocol-Buffers 2.5.0 with a **protocol-fuffers-2.4.1 (or earlier) jar**.

Comment: Thanks. That was the first thing I've done. I have one generated file. After the upgrade, I deleted it (both from client and server), and re-compiled with protoc version 2.5.0. I also replaced the 2.4.1 jars in both client and server. 
(I've compiled the lib jars myself, I wonder if it's possible that the 2.5.0 lib itself got compiled with my than enabled 2.4.1...)

Comment: An easy error to make is to recompile the Descriptor proto with the old protoc version. The error looks like there some reference to 2.4.1 hanging around somewhere. I can not suggest where though.

Comment: I compiled my descriptor.proto with the correct protoc to begin with. Unfortunately it's something else

Comment: @Permaquid that's a new idea. You should make that a separate answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @uval your messages indicates you are using Classes generated with 2.5 with a earlier (2.4.1) or earlier Protocol-Buffers jar; I will add this into the answer

Comment: Yes of course - I replaced the jars to 2.5.0 and with your suggestion I made sure that I re-compiled everything with 2.5.0, but it didn't solve my case. @Permaquid questions the assumption that the build setup is correct. I'm *almost* sure I verified that, but I'm not 100$ certain. Worth another try.

Comment: Sorry, comment should be  your messages indicates you are using Classes generated with 2.5.0 but you are running with a earlier (2.4.1) or earlier Protocol-Buffers jar. So check what jars are on the class path when you run the program. You should find that protocol-Buffers-2.4.1 (or earlier) in the class path. Protocol-Buffers-2.5.0 may be there as well

Answer (score 2):

A similar thing happened to me when I was compiling an application after upgrading to 2.5. Eventually I realized that the old 2.4 jar was still in the same folder as the new 2.5 jar, and that the build system xml file was still referring to the old one. It was just a matter of being a little more careful - nothing mysterious was going on.