# Java code has many errors after the protoc compiled

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Why does the class generated by protoc generates the following compile errors?

```
Description Resource Path Location Type Cannot override the final method
from GeneratedMessage AddressBookProtos.java
/monitor/src/main/resources/com/example/tutorial line 102 Java Problem
Cannot override the final method from GeneratedMessage
AddressBookProtos.java /monitor/src/main/resources/com/example/tutorial
line 339 Java Problem Cannot override the final method from
GeneratedMessage AddressBookProtos.java
```

and my pom.xml::

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You may have the same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16146992/980776. Try to use protobuf-java version 2.5.0.

Comment: compiler libprotoc 2.6.1  must be with  protoc2.6.1jar..thanks a lot

Comment: I've got something similar with the protobuf maven reference and the protoc versions matching at 3.14.0

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that your pom file is relevant here. The error messages are quite clear: you ***cannot override the final method***. The word *final* is used for the methods to avoid overriding, so removing final should help, otherwise include the code.

Comment: it's not the problem.maybe my desc not clear.  protoc complie java sorcecode ....i want to know why the generated sourceCode has so many errors!

Comment: compiler libprotoc 2.6.1  must be with  protoc2.6.1jar

Comment: The error is with protobuf not why does the code not compile